# Select Distinct retorna dados repetidos quando utilizo Row_Number

Tags: sql, sql-select, paginação

Estou tentando fazer paginação com `SQLServer 2008` da seguinte forma:

```
WITH CTEResults AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    SolicitacaoServico.AutoId       AS Id_Solicitacao,
    Pessoa.Nome                     AS Nome,
    Beneficiario.Codigo             AS Codigo_Beneficiario,
    SolicitacaoServico.Codigo       AS Cod_Solicitacao,
    ServicoOperadora.Codigo         AS Cod_Servico,
    ServicoOperadora.Nome           AS Servico,
    CONVERT (INTEGER, ItemSolServico.QteSolicitada) AS Qtd_Solicitada,
    CONVERT (VARCHAR, SolicitacaoServico.DataSolicitacao, 103) AS Dt_Solicitacao,
    CONVERT (VARCHAR, SolicitacaoServico.DataSolicitacao, 108) AS Hora,
    TransacaoSolicitacao.Atendente,

    CASE WHEN (SolicitacaoServico.CanalSolicitacao IN ('90')) THEN
             'HILUM' 
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN (SolicitacaoServico.CanalSolicitacao IN ('1')) THEN
             'BALCÃO' 
    ELSE         
              'OUTROS'    
            END
        END AS Canal_Solicitacao,
        TipoParSolServico.Nome AS Parecer,
        TipoSituacaoSolServico.Nome AS Situacao,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR, SolicitacaoServico.TelosUpDt, 103) AS Dt_Final,
        CONVERT (VARCHAR, SolicitacaoServico.TelosUpDt, 108) AS Hora_Final,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SolicitacaoServico.AutoId) AS RowNum


FROM
    SolicitacaoServico  WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN ItemSolServico       WITH (NOLOCK) ON ItemSolServico.Solicitacao = SolicitacaoServico.AutoId
    INNER JOIN ServicoOperadora     WITH (NOLOCK) ON ItemSolServico.Servico = ServicoOperadora.AutoId
    INNER JOIN TransacaoSolicitacao WITH (NOLOCK) ON TransacaoSolicitacao.SolicitacaoServico = SolicitacaoServico.AutoId
    LEFT JOIN TipoParSolServico     WITH (NOLOCK) ON SolicitacaoServico.Parecer = TipoParSolServico.Codigo
    LEFT JOIN TipoSituacaoSolServico    WITH (NOLOCK) ON SolicitacaoServico.Situacao = TipoSituacaoSolServico.Codigo
    INNER JOIN Beneficiario         WITH (NOLOCK) ON SolicitacaoServico.Beneficiario = Beneficiario.AutoId
    INNER JOIN Pessoa               WITH (NOLOCK) ON Beneficiario.Pessoa = Pessoa.AutoId 

WHERE 
    SolicitacaoServico.DataSolicitacao BETWEEN  ('2016-01-01 00:00:00.000') AND (GETDATE())
    AND Beneficiario.Codigo     LIKE    '117%'
    AND Beneficiario.Tipo       NOT IN  ('9')
    AND SolicitacaoServico.Codigo = 43568861

)
SELECT Distinct *
FROM CTEResults
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 40;
```

Porém o retorno vem com 5x mais dados. Quando faço essa mesma consulta com apenas o primeiro `Select` e sem esse trecho:  `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SolicitacaoServico.AutoId) AS RowNu` apenas duas linhas são retornadas, porém se faço da maneira como postei 10 linhas são retornadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acho que o `Disctint` não está funcionando quando o utilizo em conjunto com o `Row_Number()`, Como esse problema poderia ser resolvido?

Comment: Acredito que o problema está em algum JOIN, o AutoId ou Codigo se repete em alguma tabela?

Comment: N sei pois quando tiro o trecho do Row_number funciona

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem razão na sua suposição. É exatamente o `ROW_NUMBER` que está produzindo a saída dessa maneira. Note que você faz um `DISTINCT`, mas o `ROW_NUMBER` está produzindo uma sequencia de `1` a `n` registros. Como tudo é distinto entre `1` e `n`, a saída produz os 10 registros.

Uma maneira de resolver é alterar o SQL da maneira abaixo. Note que o SQL é feito normalmente sem o `RowNum` e, em cima desse SQL, outro é feito consultando os campos e colocando um `ROW_NUMBER` pra cada um. Enfim, primeiro o *dataset* esperado (com os dois registros) é produzido e em cima desse *dataset* o `ROW_NUMBER` é colocado.

```
WITH CTEResults AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY query.Id_Solicitacao) AS RowNum FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT
            SolicitacaoServico.AutoId       AS Id_Solicitacao,
            Pessoa.Nome                     AS Nome,
            Beneficiario.Codigo             AS Codigo_Beneficiario,
            SolicitacaoServico.Codigo       AS Cod_Solicitacao,
            ServicoOperadora.Codigo         AS Cod_Servico,
            ServicoOperadora.Nome           AS Servico,
            CONVERT (INTEGER, ItemSolServico.QteSolicitada) AS Qtd_Solicitada,
            CONVERT (VARCHAR, SolicitacaoServico.DataSolicitacao, 103) AS Dt_Solicitacao,
            CONVERT (VARCHAR, SolicitacaoServico.DataSolicitacao, 108) AS Hora,
            TransacaoSolicitacao.Atendente,

            CASE WHEN (SolicitacaoServico.CanalSolicitacao IN ('90')) THEN
                       'HILUM' 
            ELSE
                  CASE WHEN (SolicitacaoServico.CanalSolicitacao IN ('1')) THEN
                       'BALCÃO' 
            ELSE         
                        'OUTROS'    
                      END
                  END AS Canal_Solicitacao,
                  TipoParSolServico.Nome AS Parecer,
                  TipoSituacaoSolServico.Nome AS Situacao,
                  CONVERT (VARCHAR, SolicitacaoServico.TelosUpDt, 103) AS Dt_Final,
                  CONVERT (VARCHAR, SolicitacaoServico.TelosUpDt, 108) AS Hora_Final


            FROM
                    SolicitacaoServico  WITH (NOLOCK)
                    INNER JOIN ItemSolServico       WITH (NOLOCK) ON ItemSolServico.Solicitacao = SolicitacaoServico.AutoId
                    INNER JOIN ServicoOperadora     WITH (NOLOCK) ON ItemSolServico.Servico = ServicoOperadora.AutoId
                    INNER JOIN TransacaoSolicitacao WITH (NOLOCK) ON TransacaoSolicitacao.SolicitacaoServico = SolicitacaoServico.AutoId
                    LEFT JOIN TipoParSolServico     WITH (NOLOCK) ON SolicitacaoServico.Parecer = TipoParSolServico.Codigo
                    LEFT JOIN TipoSituacaoSolServico    WITH (NOLOCK) ON SolicitacaoServico.Situacao = TipoSituacaoSolServico.Codigo
                    INNER JOIN Beneficiario         WITH (NOLOCK) ON SolicitacaoServico.Beneficiario = Beneficiario.AutoId
                    INNER JOIN Pessoa               WITH (NOLOCK) ON Beneficiario.Pessoa = Pessoa.AutoId 

            WHERE 
                    SolicitacaoServico.DataSolicitacao BETWEEN  ('2016-01-01 00:00:00.000') AND (GETDATE())
                    AND Beneficiario.Codigo     LIKE    '117%'
                    AND Beneficiario.Tipo       NOT IN  ('9')
                    AND SolicitacaoServico.Codigo = 43568861
    ) query
)
SELECT *
FROM CTEResults
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 40;
```

Comment: Aquela "query" depois do pen ultimo parênteses é assim mesmo?

Comment: @Techies, isso é um alias pra esse SQL. Se você não colocar um nome não funciona. Esse nome é utilizado, dentre outras coisas, pra fazer um eventual join desse dataset com outra tabela ou mesmo com outro dataset. O nome fica a seu critério. Coloquei query por ser algo simples e que representa o que está sendo feito.

Comment: Entendi, está dando alguns erros no segundo From, sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: `Mensagem 156, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 31 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.`

Comment: Eu não testei. Vou fazer algo similiar aqui e já já te retorno.

Comment: Arrumei já, era uma vírgula. rs vou dar uma relida no SQL pra procurar os outros.

Comment: blza pura. Estava montando o teste aqui, mas vou ficar em standby até que você valide a solução.

Comment: Pronto, alterei no começo pra `(ORDER BY query.Id_Solicitacao)` e funcionou

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. :D

Comment: Edite e altere o SQL, por favor. Assim fica documentado da maneira que funcionou.